# Concurrent cache

Tags: concurrency, c++11

I'm looking for a concurrent cache structure. I'm using the PPL from Microsoft so I have the `concurrent_unordered_map` class, but it doesn't quite seem to be what I need. I've got a hash value and I need to associate it with a pointer type, or return that pointer if it was already in the cache. I'm not using LRU or MRU cache strategy and values wil never be removed, so it's more like a concurrent memoize.

Would it be simpler to just lock an existing `std::unordered_map`?

Comment: What exactly is wrong with using `concurrent_unordered_map`? The unordered map is a hash structure and you say you have a hash value, so...

Comment: @Zan Lynx: Because the interface does not offer insertion only if not present in a single atomic operation. It would not be thread-safe to guarantee only one insertion based on the existing interface.

Comment: That is a very important piece of information that should be part of your question and probably the title.

Comment: I suppose it is in the question if read carefully, but it didn't jump out at me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the Microsoft PPL. I just looked at the Intel Thread Building Blocks header files for Intel's concurrent_unordered_map and its `insert` function returns `false` as the second part of the returned pair when the key is already in the map.

This seems to be exactly what you need. Do the insert and if it returns `true` then it was a new insert. If it returns `false` then it was already in the map.

Edit: There seems to be some confusion here. I didn't mean that you should always run the insert. I meant that you should look for the value and if it is missing then attempt the insert. Two or more threads may occasionally race on the insert and so work will be duplicated, but this should be a rare event.

Comment: No, that's not what I need, because by the time I get a duplicate insert, it's too late to get the behaviour I need.

Comment: @DeadMG: Then I guess you have to explain what you need much more carefully.

Comment: It's a concurrent memoize. Memoizing is defined as only running the function once. Inserting twice would be running the function twice.

Comment: @DeadMG: Unless your function has side effects, which it probably shouldn't, then who cares if you occasionally run it twice?

Comment: Memoizing is used for very performance-intensive functions which are very expensive to run twice. More importantly, in this case then I am heap-allocating the result and referential equality is needed in the return value. If I insert twice, then not only did I waste potentially a lot of time, but I also lost the original value, and now the results won't compare equal.

Comment: @DeadMG: Ok. Well, your problem here is not in any way related to the topic of your question. You should write a whole new question in my opinion.

Comment: @DeadMG: Also, it seems to me there's a simple solution to the problem. Insert the memoized key with a place-holder value that indicates "computation in progress". Threads that pull that value then pile up on a condition variable/semaphore until the result is ready. More complicated but probably the only way to get what you want.

Comment: I called it a concurrent memoize in my question. It seems to me that you just don't know what memoizing is.